# Simple JSON not working in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

def getData
    file = open("http://goo.gl/BI6h7a")
    @json = JSON.parse(file.read)
end

getData

cveIds = @json['cve_id']
puts cveIds
```

You can see the JSON response here: http://goo.gl/BI6h7a

Console:

```
./cve.rb:13:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError) from ./cve.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

I don't know why this is happening. "Convert String into Integer"? WHAT?

The `@json` gets the content fine, but the `cveIds` doesn't.

Comment: In most simple words. `JSON.parse(file.read)` is returning array of records. So Parse it as array and you are done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top element in the json that you're reading is actually an Array, each of its elements is actually a hash, it's like this:

```
[
    {
        "cve_id": "CVE-2014-3976"
        // other key/value pairs
    }
    {
        "cve_id": "CVE-2014-3975"
        // other key/value pairs
    }
    {
        "cve_id": "CVE-2014-3974"
        // other key/value pairs
    }
    // .... more hashes
]
```

so `@json` is an array. And if you want to access any of its elements you have to access it with a *numeric integer* index like, so:

```
@json[0] # => { "cve_id": "CVE-2014-3976", // other key/value pairs }
```

I think you are trying to collect the `cve_id` fields of all these hashes, this can be done as follows:

```
cveIds = @json.collect { |h| h["cve_id"] }

# The result:
=> ["CVE-2014-3976", "CVE-2014-3975", "CVE-2014-3974", "CVE-2014-3962", "CVE-2014-3961",
"CVE-2014-3878", "CVE-2014-3871", "CVE-2014-3842", "CVE-2014-3806", "CVE-2014-3792",
"CVE-2014-3791", "CVE-2014-3443", "CVE-2014-3247", "CVE-2014-3246", "CVE-2014-3225",
"CVE-2014-3216", "CVE-2014-3139", "CVE-2014-3138", "CVE-2014-3008", "CVE-2014-2996",
"CVE-2014-2994", "CVE-2014-2976", "CVE-2014-2850", "CVE-2014-2847", "CVE-2014-2671",
"CVE-2014-2668", "CVE-2014-2588", "CVE-2014-2587","CVE-2014-2586", "CVE-2014-2579"]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. This `.collect` iterate through the array and create a var `h` and get each ID, right?

Comment: @Juan the `.collect` method of `Array` will iterate and in each iteration `h` is the name of the current element. The result of `collect` is a new array whose values are the values returned from each iteration, which in our case is `h["cve_id"]`. You need to practice it in order to understand it better :) [Array collect instance method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-collect)

Comment: That's what I'm doing here, practicing, create some "good for nothing" programs. Thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a `ruby` developer but what you have there is a list if dictionaries. 
My guess in order for you to read `cve_id` you need to create some kind of a for loop.

for example in `python` I would write it like this:

```
for line in my_data:
  print line['cve_id']
```

I guess in ruby it would look like this:

```
for i in @json do
    cveIds = i['cve_id']
    puts cveIds
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cveIds = @json['cve_id']
```

What are you doing here is equivalent to:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
puts arr["hello"] # using a string here on an indexed based array!
```

Hence your error message about Ruby trying to convert a `String` to an `int`.

Try the following instead

```
cveIds = @json.first['cve_id'] # equivalent to @json[0]['cve_id']
puts cveIds
```

In the above code sample, we are getting the first element from the array, which is a hash we can then access `cve_id` from.